# How to add a secondary Axis to a graph in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to show two series of data in one graph. I was able to do so, but I need a second Y axis in the right. Is there a way to add a second Y-axis without using other tools and extensions?

My Controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult PerformanceChart(){
xVals = {...}
yVals = {...}
var myChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 500, theme:ChartTheme.Green)
                .AddTitle("FSA Monthly Report").AddLegend(title: "% Backup vs Day", name: "File Server Backup Chart")
            .AddSeries(
            chartType:"Line", 
                name: "Total Success",
                xValue: xVals.ToList(),
                yValues: yVals.ToList());

            myChart.AddSeries(chartType: "StackedArea",
                name: "Daily Archiving", 
                xValue: xVals.ToList(),
                yValues: dailyArchive).Write();

            myChart.Save("~/Content/PerformanceChart", "jpeg");
            // Return the contents of the Stream to the client
            return base.File("~/Content/PerformanceChart", "jpeg");}
```

My cshtml looks like this:

```
<div style="margin-left:5%; margin-top:1em; float: left; width: 90%; height:auto;">
    <div style="height:inherit; width:inherit;">
        <p><img style="height:90%; width:96%;" src="@Url.Action("PerformanceChart")" alt="Cricketers" /> </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?